# Nginx redirect to non-https address failes in Firefox

Tags: nginx

On a website which currently is serving on `HTTPS`, I want to redirect some pages to `HTTP` and not use `SSL` on them. In nginx I configured it like this:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
      root /var/some/where;
  }

  location /secure {
      return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server{
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  include ssl_params;
  location /secure {
      root /var/some/where/secure;
  }

  location / {
      return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```

Using `curl` I can see everything is fine as follow:

```
$ curl -sIL https://example.com/ | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -sIL http://example.com/ | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

But when I try to open `HTTPS` url in `Firefox`, I'll get this error:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly. 
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. 
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies
```

Using a private window, when I try to open url in `HTTP` for the first time, is OK. But as soon as I refresh the page, It'll be redirected to `HTTPS` scheme and the error will appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000` as result of `curl -i -L` on target domain, which means `hsts` header exists and by definition:

> tells your browser to always connect to a particular domain over HTTPS. Attackers aren’t able to downgrade connections, and users can’t ignore TLS warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a certificate set up? None showing in your config.

The way it works is to open the secure connection (using the certificate) then return the content (including any redirect). It is not possible to redirect **before** creating the secure connection (as that would be a huge security risk to https if it was possible).

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I've updated the post, so now it is showing I'm loading some SSL related variables in it.

Comment: I still don't see a ssl_certificate and ssl_certifucate_key config. See here for examples: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm

Comment: They are all defined in `ssl_params`. There is no problem with `SSL`, as I said it is working now.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't get that. Isn't /secure a subset of / ? So with above config if you go to /secure won't you be directed to http, then to https, then to http, then to https... Etc. So shouldn't you remove the redirect to https under the port 80 server?

Comment: According to Nginx documentation, Request will hit the longest location definition which is match. In this case /secure is longer than /, so it'll hit /secure.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is your page is somehow redirecting to https using JavaScript (which is then entering the never ending redirect root).

Comment: Yeah it's a lot like what is happening, but why for the first time I open the page in a new browser (as I said in last line), this redirection is not happening. I also tried to find out some cookie to be the cause. With no chance I can't find anything.

Comment: Exactly. Sounds like first page is setting cookie and second page is seeing that cookie and triggering the redirect. Does it happen on Chrome? Not as familiar with Firefox but if it was chrome then I'd use Network tab in Chrome Developer tools with preserve log ticked to see what was triggering the redirect (a server level 301 or 302, Chrome itself with 307 or neither and due to Javascript).

Comment: I've tried chrome's `cookie inspector` plugin. But there is not any secure cookie at all.

Comment: Can you see in network tab what's causing the redirect as per previous comment?