# Can't redirect https for http

Tags: .htaccess, html5boilerplate

Some versions of Chrome automatically add https to my site addres. So I need to redirect https to http, because I don't have SSL certificate. I'm trying this, with no result:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you behind a load balancer? Also I don't think Chrome is doing this. That would be chaos for millions of site is that was the case.

Comment: Also this might help http://superuser.com/questions/565409/chrome-how-to-stop-redirect-from-http-to-https

Answer (score 1):

Possible repeat of this question: [Nginx redirect to non-https address failes in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425479/nginx-redirect-to-non-https-address-failes-in-firefox/33449013#33449013). Though they never got round to finding out exactly why this was happening with that person, so hopefully I'll have more luck with you.

So first of all you **cannot** redirect https to http until after the https connection succeeds - which requires a certificate. To allow this would be a huge security risk and is not the way https works. It's make https connection first, then deliver content over https. And a redirect counts as content.

Secondly you need to find out why Chrome redirects to https. Because, depending why that happens, even if you could redirect back to http if you had a cert, then you might enter a recursive loop. I'd suggest opening Chrome, pressing F12 to open developer tools, going to Network tab, clicking on preserve log, clear the network tab and clicking on "Preserve Log" and then loading the page over http and observing the redirect. If it's a 301 or 302 redirect then it's your server doing it. If it's a 307 redirect then it's due to HSTS. And it it's anything else then it's a front end app issue (i.e. Javascript on the page).